# UNIX command for moving all files and directories in a specific directory except for one individual file

Tags: unix, find, ifs, extglob

I would like to move all files except fora specific one to the trash on a mac from a single directory.

Instead of moving the files and folders within that directory I would like all files and folders to be moved individually to the trash. For this directory:

`~/Desktop/script.sh`

`~/Desktop/File1`

`~/Desktop/Folder/File2`

I would like script.sh to stay on the desktop but for the trash directory to have three elements inside it like this:

`~/.Trash/File1`

`~/.Trash/Folder`

`~/.Trash/File2`

I have found `extglob` and for the purposes of my task I will enable and disable it within my script. I am using `find` as I would like to move all directories and files and files within directories and when placed into trash I would like all the files and directories to be standalone. As in I would like a file that was in a directory to be outside that directory.

This is the code I have created and I am getting no errors.

```
shopt -s extglob
find ~/Desktop/ \( !('script.sh') \) -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' f;
do mv -- "$f" ~/.Trash ;
done
shopt -u extglob
echo Complete!
```

My question is `find` the right command for me to use for this task and if so where am I going wrong as I am able to successfully complete my task save for getting files individually sorted rather than in there parent directories within the trash.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the output you get if you change `mv -- "$f" ~/.Trash` to `echo "$f"`?

Comment: find: test: unknown primary or operator is the output that is recieved

Answer (score 0):

Change `-print0` to `-print` and remove the `-d ''` from your `read` command.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. I got this error "find: test: unknown primary or operator"